# This is stated on Monday. "3000 visas granted as of Saturday". Does it mean "......until Saturday". or "Starting from Saturday until Monday, 3000.."."

Tags: grammar, meaning, sentence-meaning, idiomatic-language, conjunctions

This is from the BBC web site: https://www.bbc.com/news/live/world-europe-60717902

**3,000 visas granted as of Saturday.**

Today is Monday. And this sentence is said today. So, I got confused what they exactly meant by saying **"......as of Saturday."**

Does it mean;

1- From the beginning of the process until Saturday, 3000 visas have been issued. (I dont know how many has been issued after Saturday until today (Monday.)

2- Starting from Saturday, 3000 visas have been issued so far. (From saturday until today(Monday), 3000 visas have been granted.)

Regards,

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["As of now", is it possible to distinguish between the meanings?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/182221/as-of-now-is-it-possible-to-distinguish-between-the-meanings) Also [Differences between 'till now', 'as of now','yet', 'up till now'](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/5198/) and ["As of now" construction](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/110848/as-of-now-construction)

Comment: Considering Kate Bunting's answer, it is clear that "as of Saturday" refers to on or before Saturday or up to Saturday, but not after Saturday. So, "as of" with a meaning "starting from ...." does not apply here. In this sentence, the man talks about the statistics that were collected until Saturday, not starting from Saturday.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A later sentence in the report makes the meaning clear.

> He (the Health Secretary) says the latest figure he has is about 3,000 as of Saturday, but adds that is likely to be higher by now.

Saturday's statistic is the latest Mr Javid has received.

Comment: So, The sentence has the meaning in the 1st sentence.

Comment: Yes, it certainly does.